# How to send selection to a NEW layer in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, layers, selections

I find that often I will duplicate a set of objects or paths then send them to a new layer.  However, in the drop-down menu and the layer menu for the selection, there are only options to move the selection up/down a layer or to an already existing layer.  I can't just go create a new layer because then my selection is deselected.  So currently, I have to anticipate that I will be needing a new layer (sometimes several operations ahead of time - because some chains of operations require that I don't lose my selection) and create it ahead of time. Is there a way to send a selection to a new layer?

Answer (score 8):

What just worked for me was to cut the selection (CTRL-X), create a new layer, and paste the selection into the new layer. I agree that a "new layer from selection" command would be nice.

Comment: This is also the way I do this operation

Comment: When pasting the selection to the new layer, we can use Ctrl+Alt+V to paste in place.

Comment: You save my life by `Ctrl+Alt+V`. Thx!

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the keyboard shortcut, there are a couple of other options:
1) Select object -> Layer Menu -> Move Selection to Layer
2) Select object -> Right Click -> Move to Layer

I found that paste in place converted vector objects to bitmaps.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help -

Create your layers, then select the object you want to move to another layer and shift+PageUp (to move 1 layer up) or shift+PageDown (to move 1 layer down)

Comment: I can tell you didn't read my post.  I explicitly mentioned that I already knew about the ability to move up/down a layer.

Comment: Sorry for that, I will do research and will let you know.

Comment: might as well delete this answer if you're still around...